# Unable to match csv column name using load records from file

Tags: csv, acumatica

I have created a new screen where I'm uploading Amazon orders from a CSV file.  The original CSV file downloaded needs to have the first few lines removed to have the column headings at the top.

Before

[image: Original CSV]

After
[image: Clean CSV]

I have a data field on the screen called date/time, but when I upload the CSV the mapping finds some sort of hidden characters in the file so the mapping doesn't automatically map the field.

[image: Upload Mapping]

I have tried changing the encoding while uploading the file, as well as changing the display name to include the ??? and double quotes like the image below, but the field doesn't auto-map.

[image]

Is there someway to get the field to auto-map on the file upload so the user doesn't have to map the field manually?
Thanks,
Kurt Bauer

Comment: These "???" most likely are not '?' but some non-unicode characters. Try to inspect the Columns popup in browser and see what is behind that ??? in real. May be copying to into Display Name will solve this. Do you get these ??? if you copy everything starting from date/time from the file to a new file?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I setup a new data provider using the source CSV file to see how Acumatica would store the field and it has the 3 question marks in the SYProviderField table.  Since the field has the double-quote I have tried to escape the character using &quot;.  While that displays correct in the column header, the mapping during import shows the &quot;.  I can just educate the client on performing the manual mapping step for the one field, but I wish it would work better.

Comment: There is an Amazon integration from Acumatica's Github repository that might help: https://github.com/Acumatica/Acumatica-AmazonIntegration